# Deployer de um projeto Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

estou fazendo um deployer do meu primeiro projeto em Spring Boot + Angular.
Tenho um servidor linux (centOS) onde peguei um tutorial para instalar o tomcat:
[tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-tomcat-on-centos/)

O tomcat está configurado conforme o tutorial, já consegui fazer o deployer de um war porém estou com problemas na hora de fazer acesso ao meu método rest.
Na tela de login quando clico no botão logar e acompanho pelo debugger do Chrome, consigo ver que é disparado o POST, mas não chega até método rest para poder fazer a autenticação.

E meu retorno (response.data) é um erro 403: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

Alguém sabe me dizer se existe alguma configuração do tomcat ou no próprio projeto do spring boot para conseguir ter esse acesso a minha classe rest?

Em modo de desenvolvimento, tudo funciona perfeitamente, agora colocando em um servidor é onde ocorre esse erro.

Estou usando para desenvolver a IDE Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz a verificação para saber se a minha classe Main fazia o extend para SpringBootServletInitializer e sim, havia essa extensão.

Uma coisa que percebi era a falta de permissão para acessar arquivos, pelo menos a mensagem dizia isso, então fui pesquisar e não achei nada concreto sobre isso.

Fiz uma liberação total da pasta tomcat do meu servidor, o problema foi resolvido:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/tomcat
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 3):

O spring boot vem com um servidor tomcat embutido e pronto para ser executada como JAR. Para que o mesmo funcione como um WAR a classe inicial Main deve extender a classe SpringBootServletInitializer.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Seria interessante dar uma olhada nos servidores embutidos. Segue documentacao do spring sobre isso.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html